# How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error when create laravel project?

Tags: laravel

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7NlW.png)

I don't know what to do to resolve this error, can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are informing you that you're missing some `PHP` dependencies, specifically the `php-dom` and `php-xml` packages.

You need to install those missing dependencies on your system (how will depend on which operating system you're using).